# mysqldump does not dump everything when running in script

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I have a mysql server running in a docker container named `dockersql`. To backup it, I use

```
docker run -ti --rm --link dockersql:mysql -v $HOME/backups/20160202/:/hostbackup mysql /bin/bash -c "mysqldump -u user -p -h mysql database > /hostbackup/mysqldump.sql"
```

This works fine. I have include this same line inside a shell backup script which does other stuff. When I run the backup script, I get only a partial dump of my USERS table. When I run only the docker run command directly in terminal, I do get the full backup of the users table.

Here is a full copy of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                    


function usage
{
 echo "dockerBackup.sh [OPTIONS] <target directory>"
 echo "    full backup of currently running environment"
 echo "  OPTIONS"
 echo "    -n prefix : will use prefix in front of data container names"
 echo "    -h : help"

}



###################################                                                                                                                                                                            
#      Main Script Execution      #                                                                                                                                                                            
###################################                                                                                                                                                                            


# prefix to be used for naming containers                                                                                                                                                                      
prefix=''

# Option analysis                                                                                                                                                                                              
while getopts 'hn:' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    h)  usage ;
          exit 0;;
    n) prefix="${OPTARG}""_" ;
       argindex=$(($argindex+2));;
     *)
        error "Unexpected option ${flag}"
        usage
        ;;
  esac
done


echo "arguments total : $# argindex : $argindex"

if [ $(($#-1)) -ne $argindex ];then
    echo "Invalid argument number $#"
    usage
    exit 1

else

backupdir=${!#}
echo "backuping to $backupdir directory"

echo "backuping mysql database"
docker run -ti --rm --link "$prefix"dockersql:mysql -v "$backupdir":/hostbackup mysql /bin/bash -c "mysqldump -u user -p -h mysql database > /hostbackup/mysqldump.sql"

 #Other backup actions

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad question, bad research before
Mysqldump works just fine whether in script or direct command line

Somewhere in another container was remaining an old file which should have been cleaned named `mysqldump.sql` that one of the actions skipped in my questions in the `#Other backup actions` part of the script was also backuping and erasing the one created by the mysql docker run command.

Sorry for any time spent and lost.